# Can a !empty input be part of a function - PHP

Tags: php, string

What I'm trying to achieve is, if there is an non empty input + another input will show up.
This is how the input looks like.

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" />
```

What I'm trying to do is something like this

```
if (!empty($input)){
    //Add another input
}
```

I think that you can get the idea, I am just wondering is this achievable, since I am new in php I don't know if this is possible.
And I'm sorry if I made any grammatical mistakes English is not my native language.

Comment: You want it to be interactive?

Comment: PHP runs server-side... you want something to run client-side?  If so, you need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! By looking at [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) you can get an idea whether the input contained something or not. Then you can make that `if` and render an additional `<input>` as necessary.

Note though that PHP is server side code. It runs when the form is submitted in the browser and thus the browser makes a request to the server. If you want the additional input to appear immediately, as soon as the first input is filled, you'll need to use JavaScript. That's also quite possible.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, you want interactivity. In which case, you will need to use JavaScript, which is a **[client side language](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/171203/38223)**.

You hook an event to the input, and check each time it's changed to see if it's empty. If it is, you display another input.

Comment: Aha, could you give me a hint what the event should be like, so I can search for a tutorial or something?!

Comment: @Walon: Search for `input onkeydown`. I recommend [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onkeydown)

Answer (score 0):

You can see if the file was empty by using:

```
if ($_FILES['image']['size'] > 0)
```